# make a mask for each well in a grid

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix, fft

I have a grid of wells in an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbLCF.jpg) and I'm trying to analyze this in Matlab. I want to create a box around each well to use as a mask. The way I am trying to go about this is to find the offset vectors from the X and Y normal and then use that to make a grid since I know the size of the wells.

I can mask out some of the wells but not all of them---but this doesn't matter since I know that there is a well in every position (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hooYS.jpg)). I can use regionprops to get the centers but I can't figure out how to move to the next step.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2U4u.jpg) is an image with the centers I can extract

Some people have suggested that I do an FFT of the image but I can't get it to work. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CbVe.jpg) is the mask with the centers from the centroid feature of regionprops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's a quick and dirty 2 cents:

First blur and invert the image so that the well lines will have high intensity values vs the rest, and further analysis will be less sensitive to noise:

```
im=double(imread('im.jpg'));
im=conv2(im,fspecial('Gaussian',10,1),'same');
im2=abs(im-max(im(:)));
```

Then, take a local threshold using the average intensity around a neighborhood of (more or less) a well size (~200 pixels)

```
im3=imfilter(im2,fspecial('average',200),'replicate');
im4=im2-im3;
bw=im2bw(im4,0);
```

Fill holes (or wells):

```
[bw2,locations] = imfill(bw,'holes');
```

Remove objects smaller than some size:

```
bw3 = bwareaopen(bw2, 2000, 8);

imagesc(bw3);
```

[image]

You can take it from there...

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you! How did you come up with this series of filters to use?

Comment: once upon a time, I too, read the documentation :) ... the rest will follow.

Comment: mind you, there are more sophisticated ways to segment the wells out. This is really quick n dirty...

Comment: This is more than adequate for my purposes. I've read a lot of the documentation but it doesn't explain how to put everything together. When to use a gaussian and why to use it etc.

Comment: the use a Gaussian is just to blur. there are several ways to reduce noise, convolution with a Gaussian filter is one of them. read about this as well as median filtering, Wiener filtering etc...  Also be aware of http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I just want to thank you again. You provided me with a starting point and I've improved the performance of this code on other images using the edge function with a dilation instead of im2bw.